# EF migration seeding enum to one migrationBuilder.InsertData

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an enum type FooNames and I am trying to seed a database table Foo from the enum values. There is an entity type Foo that corresponds to the table Foo.

```
class Foo
{
    [Key]
    [Index("pk")]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //forcing ef migration to not generate identity
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("description", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(50) ]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the enum that will seed the description column

```
enum FooNames
 {
    Created =1,
    Pending,
    Approved,
    Reconciled,
    Cancelled,
    Failed,
    Error 
}
```

In dbcontext `OnModelCreating()` I have the following code

```
foreach (FooNames name in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FooNames)))
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasData(new Foo
    {
        Id = (int)name,
        Description = name.ToString()
    });
}
```

This is generating this code in migration file

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Foo",
        columns: new[] { "id", "description" },
        values: new object[,]
        {
            { 1, "Created" },
            { 2, "Pending" },
            { 3, "Approved" },
            { 4, "Reconciled" },
            { 5, "Cancelled" },
            { 6, "Failed" },
            { 7, "Error" }
        });
```

Is it possible to force migration framework to generate separate Insert statements for each value (so 7 separate 'migrationBuilder.InsertData()' calls)? I am trying to support SQL Server 2005, which does not have multiple rows in single INSERT statement.

Comment: ...why one earth are you still targeting SQL Server 2005? It's entirely obsolete, unsupported, and (probably) insecure by now.

Comment: `enum FooNames` <-- If you're storing enums as `int` values in a DB you **must** set explicit values for every member, otherwise making changes to the enum like reordering or adding/removing items will reset the numbering and render your saved `int` values useless.

Comment: ...and if you're storing enums as int values in a database there's little need to store textual descriptions of each enum member in the DB. If you want to ensure the saved `int` values are defined then use a `CHECK ( colName IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )` constraint, which is also _waaaay_ faster than a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

Comment: @Dai because it is still in production in my company and there is a lot of red tape considering migrating it, but we need to get moving with more recent code

Comment: To my knowledge, EF dropped supported for SQL Server 2005 when .NET 4.5 came out (that was over 10 years ago...) - and if you're now using EFCore [then the minimum supported version is SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it, I manually wrote this code to generate separate insert satement

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Foo",
        columns: new[] { "status_id", "description" },
        values: new object[] { 1, "Created" });

    migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Foo",
        columns: new[] { "status_id", "description" },
        values: new object[] { 2, "Pending" });

    migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Foo",
        columns: new[] { "status_id", "description" },
        values: new object[] { 3, "Approved" });
```